# Redux Data Fetch and Rendering Happens at the same time React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am having difficulty dispatching an accessing items from the store in my React Native application using expo.

I would like to dispatch my data listing function when the user accesses the component and then list it.

```
const Flows = ({navigation}) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const {invoices, loading, error} = useSelector(state => state.invoiceList);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listInvoices());
    console.log(`list invoices dispatched`);
  }, []);

  console.log(`invoices ` + invoices || undefined);
  console.log(`loading ` + loading);
  console.log(`error ` + error);
```

Then comes the rendering.

The logs that I am getting when I open this screen are

```
invoices 
loading undefined
error undefined
list invoices dispatched
invoices undefined
loading true
error undefined
invoices [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
loading false
error undefined
```

The problem arises when I try to access an object inside invoices I get a `undefined is not an object (evaluating invoices.data)` error.

I think because until invoices data is fetched and is in the store, the component tries to access `invoices.data` which is undefined before store updates. However, this throws an error although eventually store is updated.

How do you solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, verify is the `invoices` is holding the list in the redux state. if it is so then follow:

Before accessing any values in `invoices` list, add a check for `null` or `undefined`

```js
const Flows = ({navigation}) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const {invoices, loading, error} = useSelector(state => state.invoiceList);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listInvoices());
    console.log(`list invoices dispatched`);
  }, []);

  console.log(`invoices ` + invoices || undefined);
  console.log(`loading ` + loading);
  console.log(`error ` + error);
  
  // show error UI
  if(error){
     return <ErrorText />
  }
  // handle UI if invoices is null/undefined
  if(loader || !invoices || invoices.length === 0) {
    // show loader
    return <Loader />
  }
  return <List />
 }
```

Comment: Thanks - that is useful indeed

Answer (score 0):

simple put Optional chaining (?.), The ?. operator is like the . chaining operator, except that instead of causing an error if a reference is nullish (null or undefined)

Access it like this will not throw error

```
invoices?.data
```

reference: //developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you happen to know if this is the standard way of doing this?

Comment: Btw still I am just getting null data because the component does not rerender after store is set. I am using useeffect to do that like this: `useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listInvoices());
    console.log(`list invoices dispatched`);
  }, [dispatch]);`

Comment: pass invoices in the useEffect 2nd parameter array, instead of dispatch, and try.

Comment: useEffect(() => {     dispatch(listInvoices());     console.log(list invoices dispatched);   }, [invoices]);
do it like this and you need to show loader something like that when there is no data in invoices variable

Comment: Tried that. That creates a loop, the useEffect constantly runs. I thought there would be a much more generic way of doing this as anyone needs to access datapoints from store in the application pages. Any idea on how you normally do this?